# Returning a continuous output after a Regex applied on a column

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with an address column, I am using regex to extract the ZIP code

df structure:

```
ID    Address
1     #1321, street 24, US 123 423
2     oppo. post office, ghana 4355 523
```

My code:

```
df['pin1'] = df['ADDRESS'].str.extract(r'(\d{3}\s\d{3})')
```

The code works fine, the problem is that I need the values under column as a continous number

Present Output:

```
ID    Address                            pin1
1     #1321, street 24, US 123 423       123 423
2     oppo. post office, ghana 4355 523  4355 523
```

Expected Output:

```
ID    Address                            pin1
1     #1321, street 24, US 123 423       123423
2     oppo. post office, ghana 4355 523  4355523
```

I tried the following but got an error:

```
df['pin'] = str.strip(df['ADDRESS'].str.extract(r'(\d{3}\s\d{3})'))
```

Error:

> descriptor 'strip' requires a 'str' object but received a 'Series'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this, simplest is to make a an additional call to [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
In [169]:
df['Address'].str.extract(r'(\d{3}\s\d{3})').str.replace(" ","")

Out[169]:
0    123423
1    355523
Name: Address, dtype: object
```

You could also [`split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and then [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.join.html) but this is excessive given the above:

```
In [172]:
df['Address'].str.extract(r'(\d{3}\s\d{3})').str.split(' ').str.join('')

Out[172]:
0    123423
1    355523
dtype: object
```

Additionally:

```
df['pin'] = str.strip(df['ADDRESS'].str.extract(r'(\d{3}\s\d{3})'))
```

The error here is that `str` doesn't understand pandas `Series` objects, even if you called `apply` with this:

```
In [178]:
df['Address'].str.extract(r'(\d{3}\s\d{3})').apply(str.strip)

Out[178]:
0    123 423
1    355 523
Name: Address, dtype: object
```

it still doesn't work, this is why you need to call `str.split` and then `str.join` like in my second code snippet

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I liked both the options

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the space to get rid of it:

```
df['pin1'] = df['ADDRESS'].str.extract(r'(\d{3}\s\d{3})').str.replace(" ","")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quickest solution

Answer (score 1):

You can [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) arbitrary whitespace - `\s*` with empty string:

```
df['pin1'] = df['Address'].str.extract(r'(\d{3}\s\d{3})').str.replace("\s*","")
print df

   ID                            Address    pin1
0   1       #1321, street 24, US 123 423  123423
1   2  oppo. post office, ghana 4355 523  355523
```

Comment: I liked that you accounted for arbitrary number of whitespaces ! Thank you for this